# Async await not returning/showing any data from API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 6 + Angular 14 app where for now I am trying to output data I get from an API...

I have created a service where I am getting the data from API and then I call the service in the component... The app compiles with no errors and there are no errors in the console in the browser...

Could someone help me figure out where I messed up?

Here is the code of my service:

```
async getCategories() {

 const token = await Preferences.get({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' });

 const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
 this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}categories`, {headers}).subscribe(
 data => {
 this.categories = data;
    },
 error => {
 console.log('Error', error);
    }
  );
}
```

and here is the code from from the component.ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getCategories();
}

getCategories() {
 this.categories = this.categoriesService.getCategories();
}
```

Comment: Inside getCategories() you are assigning the api results to this.categorie and then you override it with the void returned from this.categoriesService.getCategories()

Comment: `getCategories()` doesn't return anything, what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lot of problems can occur when mixing `Promise` and `Observable` - I recommended use only `Observables` as long as you can, but in your case you replace it with.

```
 async getCategories() {
 const token = await Preferences.get({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' });

 const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer 
 ${token.value}`);
 try { 
   const categories = await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}categories`, {headers}));
   return categories;
   catch(err) {
     // log error
 }
}
}
```

this method will return `Promise` with the data

the best way is to use the benefits of `rxjs`, by using only `Observables`

```
getCategories() {
    return from(Preferences.get({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' })).pipe(
        switchMap(token => {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
            return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}categories`, {headers})
        })
    );
};
```

Inside your component you'll have a variable storing the `Observable` like this:

```
 this.categories$ = this.yourService.getCategories();
```

and inside your template use `async pipe` for example:

```
 <div *ngFor="let category of categories$ | async">
   <p>{{ category }}</p>
 </div>
```

I recommended also reading about [Interceptors in Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)
this is the perfect place to add the Authorization token.

good luck :)

Comment: How would I write the code to use only observables?

Comment: Thank you, but what do I have to put in my component.ts file now?

Comment: the best way is to return the `Observable` to the component without subscribing in the service - only subscribe in the component ( or better - use `async pipe` )

Comment: here you go.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to observable in the component, not in the service. The service should only return the observable. Also any async function returns a Promise which you should either await, or use .then()

Service:

```
async getCategories() {
 const token = await Preferences.get({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' });

 const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
 return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}categories`, {headers});
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getCategories();
}

getCategories() {
 this.categoriesService.getCategories().then(categoriesObservable => 
    categoriesObservable.subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error', error);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting something to the value returned from .getCategories() but this will not return any value.

Answer (score -1):

You need to review the tour of heros, seems you have a gap in your knowledge: https://angular.io/tutorial